# Accessing xlsx files in a sub directory using openlyxl. Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I have a file structure where the python script and a directory called unmerged are at the same level. In unmerged there is an xlsx file the script needs to access. How I can load that xlsx file using openpyxl. the load workbook function seems to work only with files in the same level, so is there a way I can use the path instead

edit: examples of what I tried

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook as lw
direc = str(Directory) + "/Unmerged/" + books 
#Directory is fetched from pathlib and books is the file name 
print(direc)
workbook = lw(direc)
```

this gives me an error since lw() only takes a file name and not a path

Comment: Can you please provide some basic examples of what you have tried. The input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a relative path. If `wb.xslx` is in `./my_directory/` then `load_workbook('./my_directory/wb.xlsx')`. This is not specific to openpyxl. [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/) is how path names are processed.